# How can i automate symbol uploads to Xamarin.Insights or Microsoft Mobile Center for ios with Xamarin Projects?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I figured someone else would some day ask this question too, so i'll just go ahead and share the solution, so someone else has less work digging through Mobile Centers web api process to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you add your Build Task to the csproj file of your project:

```
 <UsingTask TaskName="UploadSymbolsTask" AssemblyFile="FULLPATHTODLL\BuildTasks.dll" />
  <Target Name="ProvideDiagnosticsSymbols" AfterTargets="CopyDSYMFromMac">
    <UploadSymbolsTask DsymFolder="$(TargetDir)NAMEOFIOSAPP.app.dSYM" InsightsApiKey="YOURINSIGHTSKEY" MobileCenterApiKey="YOURMOBILECENTERKEY" MobileCenterUser="USER" MobileCenterApplicationName="APPNAME" />
  </Target>
```

This is the Build Task you need to create:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.Build.Framework;
using Microsoft.Build.Utilities;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace BuildTasks
{
    public class UploadSymbolsTask : Task
    {
        [Required]
        public string DsymFolder { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string InsightsApiKey { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string MobileCenterApiKey { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string MobileCenterApplicationName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string MobileCenterUser { get; set; }

        public override bool Execute()
        {
            WriteLogMessage($"Executing {nameof(UploadSymbolsTask)}.");

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(InsightsApiKey))
            {
                WriteLogMessage($"{nameof(InsightsApiKey)} can not be empty.");
                return false;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DsymFolder))
            {
                WriteLogMessage($"{nameof(DsymFolder)} can not be empty.");
                return false;
            }
            if (!Directory.Exists(DsymFolder))
            {
                WriteLogMessage($"{nameof(DsymFolder)} does not exist.");
                return false;
            }

            try
            {

                // curl -F "dsym=@yourAppDsym.zip;type=application/zip" https://xaapi.xamarin.com/api/dsym?apikey=[yourApiKey]
                var tmpFileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
                // we're just forcing a temporary file name - gettempfile creates it as well, createfromdirectory crashes if it exists.
                File.Delete(tmpFileName);
                ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(DsymFolder, tmpFileName, CompressionLevel.Fastest, false);
                WriteLogMessage($" Created tmp ZipFile to upload symbols at \"{tmpFileName}\".");

                ExecuteXamarinInsightsUpload(tmpFileName);
                var awaiter = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => ExecuteMobileCenterUploadAsync(tmpFileName)).GetAwaiter();
                awaiter.GetResult();

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                WriteLogMessage($"Error occured: {e.ToString()}");
                return false;
            }
        }

        private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task ExecuteMobileCenterUploadAsync(string fileName)
        {
            WriteLogMessage(" Uploading file to Mobile Center API ...");
            //  https://docs.mobile.azure.com/api/#/crash
            //  https://mobile.azure.com/users/USER/apps/APPNAME/crashes/symbols

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("X-API-Token", $"{MobileCenterApiKey}");
                WriteLogMessage("  Retrieving upload id and destination ...");
                var clientCallback = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                var postContent = new StringContent($"{{ \"symbol_type\" : \"Apple\", \"client_callback\" : \"{clientCallback}\"}}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)).Token;
                var symbolUploadInitUrl = $"https://api.mobile.azure.com/v0.1/apps/{MobileCenterUser}/{MobileCenterApplicationName}/symbol_uploads";
                WriteLogMessage($"  Initializing Symbol upload using {symbolUploadInitUrl} ...");
                var uploadRequest = await client.PostAsync(
                    symbolUploadInitUrl,
                    postContent,
                    cancellationToken);
                var symbolUploadInitializeResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MobileCenterStartSymbolUploadResponse>(await uploadRequest.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

                WriteLogMessage($"  Uploading as symbol {symbolUploadInitializeResult.symbol_upload_id} to {symbolUploadInitializeResult.upload_url} ...");

                WriteLogMessage("  Uploading file ...");
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    using (var streamContent = new StreamContent(fileStream))
                    {
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob");
                        var uploadResult = await client.PutAsync(symbolUploadInitializeResult.upload_url, streamContent);
                        WriteLogMessage($"  Response: {uploadResult.StatusCode}");
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("x-ms-blob-type");
                    }
                }

                var symbolCommitUrl = $"https://api.mobile.azure.com/v0.1/apps/{MobileCenterUser}/{MobileCenterApplicationName}/symbol_uploads/{symbolUploadInitializeResult.symbol_upload_id}";
                WriteLogMessage($"  Commiting upload using {symbolCommitUrl} ...");

            var commitRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(
                    new HttpMethod("PATCH"), symbolCommitUrl);
                commitRequestMessage.Content = new StringContent("{ \"status\" : \"committed\" }", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                using (var commitResponse = await client.SendAsync(
                    commitRequestMessage, 
                    new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)).Token))
                {
                    var responseContent = await commitResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var commitResponseDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MobileCenterSymbolUploadResultResponse>(responseContent);
                    WriteLogMessage($"  Response: {commitResponseDeserialized.status}");
                }

                WriteLogMessage(" Done.");
            }
        }


        private void ExecuteXamarinInsightsUpload(string tmpFileName)
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/zip"); ;
                WriteLogMessage(" Uploading file to Xamarin.Insights API ...");
                var response = client.UploadFile(new Uri($"https://xaapi.xamarin.com/api/dsym?apikey={InsightsApiKey}", UriKind.Absolute), tmpFileName);
                WriteLogMessage($"  Response: {Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response)}");
                WriteLogMessage(" Done.");
            }
        }

        private void WriteLogMessage(string message)
        {
            Log.LogMessage(MessageImportance.High, $"{DateTime.Now.ToString("T")} {message}");
        }
    }

    public class MobileCenterStartSymbolUploadResponse
    {
        public string symbol_upload_id { get; set; }
        public string upload_url { get; set; }
        public DateTime expiration_date { get; set; }
    }


    public class MobileCenterSymbolUploadResultResponse
    {
        public string symbol_upload_id { get; set; }
        public string app_id { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string symbol_type { get; set; }
        public Symbol[] symbols { get; set; }
        public string origin { get; set; }
    }

    public class Symbol
    {
        public string symbol_id { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string app_id { get; set; }
        public string platform { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string origin { get; set; }
        public string[] alternate_symbol_ids { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
    }



}
```